# Does "Years of experience" take a singular verb?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I was wondering whether the following sentence takes a singular or a plural verb:

> Years of experience in writing theses **has** lent him deep knowledge about engineering as a subject.

Comment: I would use "have". Others may disagree. It is one of those things where you will everyday see both used.

Comment: Yes, it takes singular -- "years of experience" here is considered equivalent to "experience gained over several years" -- the object being experience not the years. Compare "I have tons of work to do."  HTH.

Comment: @WS2 Plural won't work in this case. Each of the individual years are not lending him the knowledge, it is the cumulative experience gained over the years.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with Tushar Raj's answer: I don't think "Years of experience has taught him it's wrong" is preferable to or more correct than "Years of experience have taught him it's wrong."

My feeling is that either *have* or *has* is fine in sentences like this, and this gets some limited (because there are so few hits) support from a Google Ngram query:

[image]

"Years/years of experience have taught" is actually more common here than "years of experience has taught".

The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) has 2 hits for "years of experience has" vs. 11 hits for "years of experience have". Among the hits for "years of experience have" are sentences like "Years of experience have taught me to trust my subconscious" and "Years of experience have taught her to judge when a person is likely to...."

So I would say that *have* is fine in the sentence from the question ("Years of experience in writing theses has/have lent him deep knowledge about engineering as a subject"). *Has* may be fine too (in my opinion, it is), but it's not the only correct choice, and based on the corpus evidence that I have looked at it doesn't seem to be the most common choice, so I wouldn't say that *has* is "better".

I agree that "Years of experience have gone by so quickly" is preferable to "Years of experience has gone by so quickly".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which word in the phrase you need to agree with based on your sentence.

> Years of experience has taught him it's wrong.

`experience` is being agreed with

---

but

> Years of experience have gone by so quickly.

Doesn't make much sense; just illustrating the point that `years` is being agreed with.

---

**`has`** is the better choice for the example sentence in your OP.

Comment: Sure, but why do you think it's so?

Comment: @Kris: _has is the better choice for the example sentence in your OP_ Is your question about this?

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: So.. you agree with my answer?

Comment: We need to see that the answer is canonical. Else it would be commentary.

Comment: Can you cut to the chase and tell me your thoughts on how I could improve my answer? How is any of this commentary? And what would make it "canonical"?

Comment: Please go through the posts on this Q&A and, maybe, FAQ. Good Luck.

Comment: Please either downvote my post or edit it to your satisfaction and move on. I don't think it violates any guidelines.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74145/discussion-between-tushar-raj-and-kris).

Comment: Ingenious idea but is it observed in practice?

Comment: @WS2. Yes and no. I'd say people use `have`, like you said, quite often in cases like these. I choose to interpret that to mean the `years` have taught them (as opposed to the `experience`) which is idimatically fine.